# HTML5 - Can't Display Small Letters

Tags: android, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an `HTML5+PhoneGap+jQuery Mobile` application for `Android tablet(3.0)`.I am trying to write the following:

```
<div data-role="content"> 
    <a data-role="button" href="#sensorslist">Menu</a>              
</div><!-- /content -->
```

When I am running it using USB debugging mechanism,"`Menu`" appears as "`MENU`".
Why does it happen?What do I have to do?

Thanks!

Comment: I would check whole .css for `text-transform:uppercase;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply text-transform property in your css:

```
text-transform: none;
```

I am having similar problem.Above sentence worked for me.Hope this will help you.